# ML coursera submission (week 2) Feature Normalization

Tags: machine-learning, submit, octave, normalization

I have written the following code for section "feature normalization"

Here X is the Feature matrix (m*n) such that

```
m = number of examples 
n = number of features
```

Code

```
mu = mean(X);
sigma = std(X);
m = size(X,1);

% Subtracting the mean from each row 
for i = 1:m
    X_norm(i,:) = X(i,:)-mu;
end;

% Dividing the STD from each row 
for i = 1:m
    X_norm(i,:) = X(i,:)./sigma;
end;
```

But on submitting it to the server built for Andrew Ng's class, It's not giving me any confirmation if it's wrong or correct.

```
==
==                                   Part Name |     Score | Feedback
==                                   --------- |     ----- | --------
==                            Warm-up Exercise |  10 /  10 | Nice work!
==           Computing Cost (for One Variable) |  40 /  40 | Nice work!
==         Gradient Descent (for One Variable) |  50 /  50 | Nice work!
==                       Feature Normalization |   0 /   0 |
==     Computing Cost (for Multiple Variables) |   0 /   0 |
==   Gradient Descent (for Multiple Variables) |   0 /   0 |
==                            Normal Equations |   0 /   0 |
==                                   --------------------------------
==                                             | 100 / 100 |
```

Is this a bug in the web frontend presentation layer or my code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this iss an issue for the course administrators, not SO.

Comment: You could have instead posted this on the course's forum. This is not the right place for this issue!

Answer (score 0):

When the submit() does not give you any points, this means your answer is not correct.
This usually means, that either you have not implemented it yet, or there is a mistake in your implementation.

From what I can see, your indices are not correct. However, in order not to violate the code of conduct of this course, you should ask your question in the Coursera forum (without posting your code).

There are also tutorials with each programming exercise. Those are usually very helpful and guide you through the entire exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate for EACH feature

```
m = size(X,1);
```

What you are actually getting with m is the number of ROWS (example), but you want to get the number of COLUMNS (Features)

solution:

```
m = size(X,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for and notice that you're making mistake with dividing each row of X without subtracting to mean.

Combine both and do with less code like this -

% Subtracting the mean and Dividing the STD from each row:

```
for i = 1:m
    X_norm(i,:) = (X(i,:) - mu) ./ sigma;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the class, the final correct answer was given as `featureNormalize.m`:

```
function [X_norm, mu, sigma] = featureNormalize(X)
  %description: Normalizes the features in X
  %   FEATURENORMALIZE(X) returns a normalized version of X where
  %   the mean value of each feature is 0 and the standard deviation
  %   is 1. This is often a good preprocessing step to do when
  %   working with learning algorithms.
  
  X_norm = X;
  mu = zeros(1, size(X, 2));
  sigma = zeros(1, size(X, 2));
  
  % Instructions: First, for each feature dimension, compute the mean
  %               of the feature and subtract it from the dataset,
  %               storing the mean value in mu. Next, compute the 
  %               standard deviation of each feature and divide
  %               each feature by it's standard deviation, storing
  %               the standard deviation in sigma. 
  %
  %               Note that X is a matrix where each column is a 
  %               feature and each row is an example. You need 
  %               to perform the normalization separately for 
  %               each feature. 
  
  mu = mean(X);
  sigma = std(X);
  X_norm = (X - mu)./sigma;
end
```

If you're taking this class and feel the urge to copy and paste, you're in a grey-area on academic honesty.  You're supposed to figure it out from first principles, not google it and regurgitate the answer.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.